# How to track buses of my city in my android app?

Tags: android, gps

I'm working to create an app that track buses of a pullman's agency.
Each pullman has a GPS and my question is :
How can I connect my android app to pullman's GPS ? 
If it is possible , how can I track their movement and show on the map ?

Comment: negotiate a deal with the agency to get their GPS data

Answer (score 0):

My city's bus company is locked into a contract with some scummy, incompetent software company, won't share their data, and have taken pains to make it difficult to scrape from the nearly useless map on their website.  I figure if you had enough users (i.e., a high probability of at least one on every bus) then you could build a real-time map of the bus system without any official assistance.  The problem is bootstrapping it.  You need a good reason to attract users in the first place.  In my case, the city's website is so horrible, and doubly so on a mobile screen, that users might be lured by any usable map of bus stops and schedules.